# how do i use the flexbox in this instance?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i want the page to look like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34YXf.png)
and im not allowed to change the html so only im only allowed to style it via CSS.
the HTML i got with it is this.
what prevented me from solving it was that i could get the last 3 instances of the news class printed out the way it should be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <p>Home</p>
        <p>Our games</p>
        <p>Contact</p>
        <p>Support</p>
        <p>Log In</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="news">
            <h1>Gaming Website</h1>
            <p>
                Welcome to our website! We have a wild variety of games that you will probably like.
                Feel free to make a suggestion if you'd like to have another game added.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="news">
            <h3>Steam Support is now live</h3>
            <p>
                From now on, you can also start up games from your Steam library!
                The developers have worked hard for this functionality.
                If you have any bugs, report them at the Support page.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="news">
            <h3>Minecraft Steve confirmed for Smash?</h3>
            <p>
                Is Steve coming to Smash Ultimate?
                We have the latest hints and potential leaks to keep you
                updated about the possibility of the iconic tree-puncher
                coming to Smash Ultimate.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="breaking" class="news">
            <h3>Half-Life 3 confirmed</h3>
            <p>
                It is finally real. Since 1998, fans across the globe have been
                hoping for a conclusion to the Half-Life trilogy that was started
                ages ago.
                However, it was last Tuesday when it was announced that the game
                will be published next summer.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is as far as i got. pls correct me if i can do things easier or via another way im very new to this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkcWp.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could still use the `display: flex` on `.content`, and use a fixed width `100%` on the first child and let the other child have `flex: 1` as follows:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.news:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}

.news:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>Our games</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
    <p>Support</p>
    <p>Log In</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="news">
      <h1>Gaming Website</h1>
      <p>
        Welcome to our website! We have a wild variety of games that you will probably like. Feel free to make a suggestion if you'd like to have another game added.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
      <h3>Steam Support is now live</h3>
      <p>
        From now on, you can also start up games from your Steam library! The developers have worked hard for this functionality. If you have any bugs, report them at the Support page.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="news">
      <h3>Minecraft Steve confirmed for Smash?</h3>
      <p>
        Is Steve coming to Smash Ultimate? We have the latest hints and potential leaks to keep you updated about the possibility of the iconic tree-puncher coming to Smash Ultimate.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="breaking" class="news">
      <h3>Half-Life 3 confirmed</h3>
      <p>
        It is finally real. Since 1998, fans across the globe have been hoping for a conclusion to the Half-Life trilogy that was started ages ago. However, it was last Tuesday when it was announced that the game will be published next summer.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of having a different solutions:

### 1. column-count

> The column-count CSS property breaks an element's content into the specified number of columns.

[MDN - column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

By using `column-count: 3;` on the parent and `column-span: all;` on the first child, you will get the result you want.

```css
.content {
  column-count: 3;
}

.news:first-child {
  column-span: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="news">
    <h1>Gaming Website</h1>
    <p>
      Welcome to our website! We have a wild variety of games that you will probably like. Feel free to make a suggestion if you'd like to have another game added.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <h3>Steam Support is now live</h3>
    <p>
      From now on, you can also start up games from your Steam library! The developers have worked hard for this functionality. If you have any bugs, report them at the Support page.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <h3>Minecraft Steve confirmed for Smash?</h3>
    <p>
      Is Steve coming to Smash Ultimate? We have the latest hints and potential leaks to keep you updated about the possibility of the iconic tree-puncher coming to Smash Ultimate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="breaking" class="news">
    <h3>Half-Life 3 confirmed</h3>
    <p>
      It is finally real. Since 1998, fans across the globe have been hoping for a conclusion to the Half-Life trilogy that was started ages ago. However, it was last Tuesday when it was announced that the game will be published next summer.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 2. grid layout

> A grid is a set of intersecting horizontal and vertical lines defining columns and rows. Elements can be placed onto the grid within these column and row lines.
> [MDN - Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)

By using `display: grid;` on the parent, defining 3 columns `grid-temlplate-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);` and telling the first child to start from the first column and end at the latest one `grid-column: 1 / -1;`, you can get the result you want.

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.news:first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="news">
    <h1>Gaming Website</h1>
    <p>
      Welcome to our website! We have a wild variety of games that you will probably like. Feel free to make a suggestion if you'd like to have another game added.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <h3>Steam Support is now live</h3>
    <p>
      From now on, you can also start up games from your Steam library! The developers have worked hard for this functionality. If you have any bugs, report them at the Support page.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <h3>Minecraft Steve confirmed for Smash?</h3>
    <p>
      Is Steve coming to Smash Ultimate? We have the latest hints and potential leaks to keep you updated about the possibility of the iconic tree-puncher coming to Smash Ultimate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="breaking" class="news">
    <h3>Half-Life 3 confirmed</h3>
    <p>
      It is finally real. Since 1998, fans across the globe have been hoping for a conclusion to the Half-Life trilogy that was started ages ago. However, it was last Tuesday when it was announced that the game will be published next summer.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 3. float

> The float CSS property places an element on the left or right side of its container, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the page, though still remaining a part of the flow (in contrast to absolute positioning).

[MDN - float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

You could add `float: left` to every `.news`, defin their widths and add a clearfix to the parent.

```css
.content:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}

.news {
  float: left;
}

.news:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}

.news+.news {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="news">
    <h1>Gaming Website</h1>
    <p>
      Welcome to our website! We have a wild variety of games that you will probably like. Feel free to make a suggestion if you'd like to have another game added.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <h3>Steam Support is now live</h3>
    <p>
      From now on, you can also start up games from your Steam library! The developers have worked hard for this functionality. If you have any bugs, report them at the Support page.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <h3>Minecraft Steve confirmed for Smash?</h3>
    <p>
      Is Steve coming to Smash Ultimate? We have the latest hints and potential leaks to keep you updated about the possibility of the iconic tree-puncher coming to Smash Ultimate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="breaking" class="news">
    <h3>Half-Life 3 confirmed</h3>
    <p>
      It is finally real. Since 1998, fans across the globe have been hoping for a conclusion to the Half-Life trilogy that was started ages ago. However, it was last Tuesday when it was announced that the game will be published next summer.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 4. flex

You can check the answer from @Damzaky.